# Как правильно реализовать связанную таблицу в RestFul Api?

Tags: api, rest, архитектура

Я создаю свой менеджер задач.
В базе 3 модели:

```
Task
- id
- name
- isComplited

List
- id
- name

ListTask
- id
- listId
- taskId
```

По задумке, task может быть не привязан к списку.

Вопрос, как реализовать добавление задач в список и удаление оттудова?

Как вариант, можно создать адрес `api/listtask` и навешивать на него методы http. Хоть и логично, но выглядеть странно (не интуитивная сущность). Другой вариант, реализовать по адресу `PUT or DELETE api/list/1?taskId=1`. Тоже странно выглядит.

Хотел бы получить развернутый ответ, почему тот или иной вариант плох или хорош.

Comment: `POST api/list/LIST_ID/task` - создание, `GET api/list/LIST_ID/task` - все таски списка, `GET api/list/LIST_ID/task/TASK_ID` - просмотр таски списка `DELETE api/list/LIST_ID/task/TASK_ID` удаление и т.д.

Comment: Вариант с PUT и DELETE имеет право на существование, только taskId передавать не параметром, а в теле.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  мне кажется это неправильно. По классике REST при запросе вида `api/list/1` указывает на саму сущность, с которой нужно совершить действие, http метод указывает "что надо сделать" с ней.... А указание таски в теле и работа именно с таской в таком контексте - это какое-то UB  получается.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - согласен, что выглядит как-то неправильно. Но ведь сущность у нас является списком, поэтому добавление в него элемента является его изменением. Поэтому PUT вроде как подходит. Но с DELETE возникает неоднозначность: мы хотим удалить сам список целиком или только элемент из него? С этим не поспоришь, корявенько как-то.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поэтому я написал как раз ссылки в первом комменте. Они все будут примерно такие. Даже при изменении таски.  Сам путь `api/list/LIST_ID/task/TASK_ID`  будет указывать, что действие производится с таской конкретного списка, а http (например PUT) будет всё так же указывать, что нужно (например поменять). Да, вроде меняется и список тоже, но считаем, что указав в URL таким образом мы это визуально обозначили. Заодно и в коде не придётся это писать в классе List всю логику, а можно вынести в class Task. А этой индивидуальной логики, применяемой только к задачам может быть много

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А Адреса вида `GET/POST api/list` и `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE api/list/LIST_ID` я бы оставил только для действий со списками, не касающиеся тасков. Например поменять имя списка или его описание или владельца списка (или куча индивидуальных параметров списка), удалить конкретный список. `GET api/list?filter=...` мог бы выдать все списки с фильтром по их индивидуальным критериям, `GET api/list/LIST_ID?expand=tasks` мог бы выдать список со вложенными задачами и т.д